# Show own shortcode data on each page

Tags: pages, shortcode

I have shortcode [cities] and i need that when i import my pages to wordpress with text with this shortcode, there was own city by page id. Is it possible to do?

I created a simple shortcode:

```
add_shortcode ('cities', 'show_cities');
function show_cities(){
    return "New York";
}
```

Think that i need some array with cities and page id's but i don't understand how to do this. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Hi, could you explain a little bit more what exactly do you want to achieve? How should that shortcode work? Some examples would be great too, I guess...

Comment: For example:
i have 100 pages with special offers for cities. On each page unique city and unique offer. I need to put on each page shortcode [cities] for show right city for this page by page id. If page id 7 then show New York, if page id 10 > show Alabama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to achieve the desired functionality is to use post_meta / custom field.

```
add_shortcode ('cities', 'show_cities');
function show_cities(){
   /* 
      Create a custom field 'city' to save city name in page editor
   */

   $city = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'city', true );

   return $city;
}
```

Using an array can also do the work as under:

```
add_shortcode ('cities', 'show_cities');
function show_cities(){
   /* 
      Create an array using Page_id as index, e.g.
      $cities [ 'page_id' ] = "City Name";
   */

   $cities [ 7 ] = "New York";
   $cities [ 10 ] = "Alabama";

   return $cities [ get_the_id() ];
}
```